# POI formula evaluator not working

Tags: apache-poi

I use poi-ooxml 3.9 to generate invoice report from an excel template I store in db. I have formulas at the end of the sheet that will do sum and other tax calculations.

> ```
> cell D30 =SUM(D22:D28) 
> cell D31 =D30*0.12 
> cell D32 =D31*0.02
> cell D33 =D31*0.01
> cell D35 =SUM(D30:D33)
> ```

Before I write the sheet to a new file I evaluate the formulas, but nothing works. The code below is used to evaluate the formulas. Do I need to evaluate the formulas whenever I write the values into the cells or only at the end of the operation?

```
String formulaCells[] = { "D30", "D31", "D32", "D33", "D35" };
FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = workBook.getCreationHelper()
        .createFormulaEvaluator();
Sheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
for (String cellRef : formulaCells) {
CellReference ref = new CellReference(cellRef);
Row actualRow = sheet.getRow(ref.getRow());
Cell cell = actualRow.getCell(ref.getCol());
if (cell != null) {
// here I evaluate the formula     
formulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell);
```

anything I have missed?

Note: Only after I open the generated sheet and press enter in every cells the formulas are evaluated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that your cell are added as number?

if not, try to do something like this:

```
if(type.equals("String")) {
   cell.setCellValue (value.toString());
} else if (type.equals("int")) {
   cell.setCellValue(Integer.parseInt(value.toString()));
} else if (type.equals("double")) {
   cell.setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(value.toString()));
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right! the problems is I have set all the values as such (string). thank you! :-)